# Ignite and Spring with multiple Class Loaders

Tags: spring, caching, ignite

I have a system with Spring Cache, in it there are multiple Class Loaders.  Actually I use ehcache and it works fine:

```
@Component
public class ObjectRepository extends MongoRepository<Object> {
// -------------------------- OTHER METHODS --------------------------

    @Override
    @Cacheable(value = "object", key = "#p0+#p1.name")
    public Object get(String id, Class<? extends Object> clazz) {
        return super.get(id, clazz);
    }

    @Override
    @CacheEvict(value = "object", key = "#p0+#p1.name")
    public void remove(String id, Class<? extends Object> clazz) {
        super.remove(id, clazz);
    }

    @Override
    @CacheEvict(value = "object", key = "#p0+#p0.class.name")
    public void save(Object object) {
        super.save(object);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to change to ignite:

```
@Bean
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    SpringCacheManager springCacheManager = new SpringCacheManager();
    IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration = new IgniteConfiguration();
    igniteConfiguration.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
    igniteConfiguration.setIncludeEventTypes(org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVTS_TASK_EXECUTION);
    springCacheManager.setConfiguration(igniteConfiguration);
    return springCacheManager;
}
```

Because of multiple Class Loaders I'm getting error, when i do `objectRepository.get("1", com.test.ClassInClassLoader1.class)` works ok but after i do `objectRepository.get("2", com.test.ClassInClassLoader2.class)` and i get the error:

```
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Encountered incompatible class loaders for cache [class1=com.test.ClassInClassLoader2, class2=com.test.ClassInClassLoader1]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheDeploymentManager.registerClass(GridCacheDeploymentManager.java:656)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheDeploymentManager.registerClass(GridCacheDeploymentManager.java:601)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheDeploymentManager.registerClass(GridCacheDeploymentManager.java:590)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheDeploymentManager.registerClasses(GridCacheDeploymentManager.java:573)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheUtils.marshal(GridCacheUtils.java:950)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cacheobject.IgniteCacheObjectProcessorImpl.marshal(IgniteCacheObjectProcessorImpl.java:94)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.portable.CacheObjectPortableProcessorImpl.marshal(CacheObjectPortableProcessorImpl.java:727)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cacheobject.IgniteCacheObjectProcessorImpl$UserCacheObjectImpl.prepareForCache(IgniteCacheObjectProcessorImpl.java:343)
        ... 186 more
```

I tryied to use `DeploymentMode.ISOLATED` and `DeploymentMode.PRIVATE` but they do not work with `igniteConfiguration.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true)`, so I have to register manually all classes and i didn't find how to do it with LocalDeploymentSpi, I tried to use `igniteConfiguration.getDeploymentSpi()` but it's null and when I create it is like the Ignite ignores the classes in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend to use peer class loading for the domain model classes. Instead, you should make all your classes available on classpath of all nodes and switch peer class loading off (`igniteConfiguration.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(false)`).

Also note that starting with Ignite 1.5, which is going to be released soon, cache data will be stored in binary format by default, so you will not have to deploy classes on server nodes even if peer class loading is disabled.

Comment: I tried to use this way but i get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` because the class is not in default ClassLoader and I don't know how to register my own classes, I tried to use `igniteConfiguration.DeploymentSpi()` but it is always null and when I create `LocalDeploymentSpi` and register classes in it I get the same error. I can't put the classes in ClassPath because the ClassLoader and Classes are created in memory in runtime. If there was a way to register these classes I think it would work.

Comment: @Bruno, are you trying to call `DeploymentSpi.register(..)` method directly? You should never do this, because SPIs are pluggable components that are supposed to be used by Ignite internals. Also there is no need to explicitly configure `LocalDeploymentSpi` as it's a default one and doesn't have any additional configuration. You can try using `UriDeploymentSpi` instead and dynamically load classes from file system or other source.

Comment: @Bruno, in addition, in 1.5 Ignite will introduce binary objects, which will be used as a default format for storing data in memory. This format supports field lookups without deserialization and therefore does not require to have classes at all. You can dynamically create objects of any structure on the fly and work with them. It sounds like this feature can help you a lot with your use case.

Comment: I tried to call it and doesn't work. How can I use `UriDeploymentSpi` if my classes are in memory? And I have to put this class in `igniteConfiguration.setDeploymentSpi(...)`?

Comment: I tried to use the version 1.5.1-RC1-SNAPSHOT from git and I got the same errors, what configuration do I have to use?

Comment: @Bruno, it looks like binary format is not fully supported by `SpringCacheManager` right now. I created a ticket in Ignite JIRA for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-2095

Comment: I'll follow this ticket and meanwhile I'll try to use the 1.4 version. I don't know if I can wait too much.

Comment: @Bruno, sounds good. I'm planning to fix this in 1.5, so it should be available by the end of the year.

Comment: Good news @Valentin, so I'll wait for this version and when your ticket is ready and commited I'll test the version in github.

Comment: @Bruno, I just realized that adding this to `SpringCacheManager` doesn't make much sense, because it will require using Ignite APIs and therefore break the abstraction. I would recommend you to switch to Ignite API and use binary format. Essentially, it allows to create dynamic objects and work with them without classes at all, nor on server, neither on client. Please take a look at `BinaryObject` and `BinaryObjectBuilder` interfaces.

Comment: I already have a system with ehcache through Spring, it's not an option to me use directly the Ignite API. I'll try the way registering the classes in ignite then, how can I register a class in Ignite if I have a `ClassLoader` and `Class` in memory? As you see I tried `LocalDeploymentSpi.register(..)` and it didn't work and the other UriDeploymentSpi use a directory and file system.

Comment: @Bruno, if you have a class loader that is aware of these classes, you can provide it to Ignite via `IgniteConfiguration.setClassLoader()`. This should fix your issue.

Comment: I have a list of Class Loaders, I think this doesn't work to me.

Comment: @Bruno, you can create a wrapper classloader that will iterate through this list, delegate to each of them and stop once the class is found. Will this work?

Comment: I had exactly the same idea, this is what I'm doing now but there are chance that it doesn't work in my system.

Comment: it's working with ClassLoader Wrapper, but I'm getting other problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534251/ignite-for-hibernate-l2-is-extremely-slow