# Ignite for Hibernate L2 is extremely slow

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching, ignite

I have system with Hibernate, Spring, PostgreSQL, MongoDB, Neo4j and ElasticSearch working with EhCache for Hibernate L2 and Spring Cache, it works well.

I'm testing Ignite but the system became extremely slow when I put Ignite for Hibernate L2 (with Spring Cache works fast), I put JProfiler to see what is really slow and I just saw the follow methods extremely slow:

```
org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(byte[ ], int, int)
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.parseSql
javax.persistence.EntityManager.find
```

This doesn't make much sense to me. I'm using Ignite 1.5.1.final-SNAPSHOT from Branch 1.5.1-2 with https://github.com/apache/ignite/pull/388 (I made a change to automatically create the caches for Hibernate L2), I tested with 1.4.0 and the problem is the same.

Configuration for Ignite:

```
@Configuration
public class CacheConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DynamicClassLoaderWrapper dynamicClassLoaderWrapper() {
        return new DynamicClassLoaderWrapper(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    }

    @Bean
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration = new IgniteConfiguration();
        igniteConfiguration.setGridName("meceap-grid");
        igniteConfiguration.setClassLoader(dynamicClassLoaderWrapper());

        igniteConfiguration.setCacheConfiguration(this.createDefaultCache("br.com.bruno.model.*"),
                this.createDefaultCache("org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache"),
                this.createDefaultCache("org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache"));

        SpringCacheManager springCacheManager = new SpringCacheManager();
        springCacheManager.setConfiguration(igniteConfiguration);
        springCacheManager.setDynamicCacheConfiguration(this.createDefaultCache(null));
        return springCacheManager;
    }

    private org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration createDefaultCache(String name) {
        org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = new org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration();
        cacheConfiguration.setName(name);
        cacheConfiguration.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
        cacheConfiguration.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC);
        cacheConfiguration.setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_SYNC);
        cacheConfiguration.setStatisticsEnabled(true);
        cacheConfiguration.setEvictSynchronized(true);
        return cacheConfiguration;
    }
```

}

```
public class RepositoryConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean meceapEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        bean.setPersistenceUnitName(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        bean.setDataSource(dataSource);

        bean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);
        bean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", NamingStrategyLowerCase.class.getCanonicalName());
        bean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 0);
        bean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", true);
        bean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.show_sql", false);
        bean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("org.apache.ignite.hibernate.grid_name", "meceap-grid");
        bean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", HibernateRegionFactory.class.getCanonicalName());
        bean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", true);
        bean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", true);
        bean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode", SharedCacheMode.ALL);
        bean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.cache.default_cache_concurrency_strategy", "read-write");
        bean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.generate_statistics", true);
        bean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("javax.persistence.validation.factory", validator);

        bean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        bean.setPackagesToScan("br.com.me.ceap.model");

        meceapEntityManagerFactoryRef = bean;

        return bean;
    }
```

}

Comment: In your profiling result the cache is not being used, since it's waiting on the database. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: What is hit ratio on Ignite compared to other providers with which you don't experience the issue? Is it possible that lifetime/expiry/eviction settings are different?

Comment: Define "Extremely slow"

Comment: @Kayaman The profiler shows info like the cache is not being used but it is, if I turn off Hibernate L2 ou back to EhCache the system works normal.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic The hit ratio is the same as before with EhCache, nothing changed.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen A get through hibernate is taking minutes and I see that every execution the time increases.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like EhCache region factory is still used, so Ignite is not actually configured as the L2 cache.

You should use Ignite's `HibernateRegionFactory` instead, refer to `HibernateL2CacheExample` for example of correct configuration.

Comment: I'm sorry for the error, I put the wrong value in the text but in my application I'm using `HibernateRegionFactory` but I'll see the configuration in HibernateL2CacheExample and make more tests.

Comment: I checked the configuration in example and it's all right, in my application HIbernate Ignite L2 is really slow. I have no more ideas...

Comment: I've opened a ticket in Apache Ignite JIRA. Seems that it makes sense someone from the community to investigate this issue. @Bruno, if possible please provide a link to a reproducible example or at least some parts of the code into the JIRA ticket. It will be perfect if you share the sources over GitHub or some other tool.

Comment: @dmagda Unfortunately I can only show my configuration, the system I work is private. Put a link to the ticket and I can provide more information that they can need.

Comment: @Bruno This is [the ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-2488) in Ignite JIRA. Please specify more details there.